# First De Rham cohomology group of Cantor ternary

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-cohomology, cantor-set, de-rham-cohomology

I proved that $\mathcal H^1 (\mathbb R^2)=\mathbb 0$ and if $\{ P_1,...,P_n\ |P_i\neq P_j,\ i\neq j \}$ is an $\mathbb R^2$ subset, $\mathcal H^1 (\mathbb R^2\setminus\{P_1,...,P_n\})=\mathbb R^n $.
Thus I proved this fact: $\mathcal H^1 (\mathbb R^2\setminus(\mathbb Z×\{0\})) =\mathbb R ^ \mathbb N =\mathbb R^{\oplus \mathbb N}$

Now let's denote with $\mathcal T $ Cantor set; we know $\mathcal T $ is closed, thus its complement is open. I'm eventually wondering what $\mathcal H^1 (\mathbb R^2\setminus \mathcal (T×\{0\}) )$ is.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is even a manifold, but maybe we can try to compute singular (co)homolgy instead. I think the answer is still $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$. Since the complement of the Cantor set in $[0, 1]$ is open, so is a countable union of open intervals. Hence $$\mathbb{R}^{2} \backslash (\mathcal{T} \times\{0\}) = (\mathbb{R}^{2} \backslash [0, 1]) \cup \left(\bigcup_{i} (a_{i}, b_{i})\right)$$ and it seems that the homology should be $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ which is same as it of $\mathbb{R}^{2} \backslash (\mathbb{Z} \times \{0\})$, but I'm not sure.